# Updating or deleting a sql table for non existent record

Tags: sql

How does SQL behave and what does it return when I try updating or deleting a on existent record in the table. I checked running an update on a non existent record and the query basically runs, doesn't do anything and returns saying a no records were affected. However I wanted to understand how it works internally and what would the result variable hold after such queries.

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Feel free to add the tag for the software you are actually using.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the database but usually you can get the affected rows after update or insert.

If nothing is updated you will get `0` for the rowcount.

Pl SQL example:

```
declare
  i number;
begin
  update MyTable set status = 'someStatus' where name = 'someName';
  i := sql%rowcount;
end;
```

T-SQL example:

```
UPDATE Table Set Column = 0 WHERE Column IS NULL
SELECT @RowCount = @@ROWCOUNT
```

How it works internaly depends on the database vendor.